# Работа с таблицами-связками. Как правильно организовать права доступа пользователя к модулям на сайте?

Tags: php, mysql

В MySQL имеются таблицы:

```
users  
modules  
rights
```

Таблица `rights` содержит два поля: `uid` (id пользователя из таблицы users, внешний ключ) и `mid` (id модуля, все аналогично).

В процессе аутинтификации происходит следующий запрос:

```sql
SELECT modules.mod_name 
FROM rights 
INNER JOIN modules ON rights.mod_id = modules.mod_id 
WHERE rights.uid = 1
```

Где 1 - может быть любым числом (id юзера), а в поле `mod_name` - техническое имя модуля. Результат запроса сохраняется в массив, и в дальнейшем, при построении страниц, сверяемся с этим массивом, чтобы знать, куда юзеру можно а куда нельзя.

Кто с подобным уже сталкивался? Я все верно делаю?

PS: И еще, хочу придумать отдельный метод для работы с таблицами-связками, т.к. дальше их будет еще больше. Какой алгоритм, в этом случае, будет смотрется лучше, и грамотнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

гм... А на чем пишем, собственно? PHP? Можно взять за основу предложенный мной запрос к базе и...

```
function GetRelatedFields($tfrom, $frfield, $fcfield, $tcross, $ccfield, $crfield, $crvalue)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT ' . $tfrom . '.' . $frfield . ' FROM ' . $tfrom . ' INNER JOIN (SELECT ' . $ccfield . ' FROM ' . $tcross . ' WHERE ' . $crfield . ' = ' . $crvalue . ') AS __temptable ON ' . $fcfield . ' = ' . $ccfield . ';';
$result = false;

$res = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$res)
{
    $err = mysqli_error($link));
    // ...
}
else
{
    // fill $result array with results
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        $result[] = $row;

}
    return $result;     
}
```

- код написан прямо здесь, без проверки, поэтому копи-паст не приветствуется. $link - глобальный объект для доступа к базе. Расширение - mysqli. В общем, думаю, идея ясна. И - неограниченные возможности для расширения функционала...

Comment: Хотел знать, как делают другие. Я именно так и сделал. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, у Вас все нормально, единственное что я бы поменял - это сам запрос.

```sql
SELECT modules.mod_name 
FROM modules 
INNER JOIN (SELECT mid FROM rights WHERE uid = 1) AS am ON mod_id=mid;
```

Comment: не совсем понятно ЧТО Вы имеете в виду говоря про отдельный метод для работы с таблицами связками - какую конкретную задачу Вы предполагаете возложить на тот метод???

Comment: Чтобы по ходу дальнейшего программирования не заморачиваться с составлением запросов, и подключением к базе. А просто вызывать этот метод, передавая имя нужной таблицы, имя таблицы-справочника, и список нужных полей, и получать в результате массив данных.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, суть вопроса не понял.
Но попытаюсь ответить.
Вы хотите запретить/разрешить посещение различных страниц различным пользователям.
Для этого есть система групп. Т.е. каждый пользователь находится в определённой группе, админы в админах модеры в модерах спаммеры в забаненых.
Ну вот и суть такова. Вы создаете таблицу групп, id, name, homepage, ну и прочие общие штуки для групп, и каждому юзеру назначаешь id группы.
Затем, вы, просто впишете функцию chekPrivileges, в которую передаёшь массив id-шек, которым можно посещать эту страницу, или же внутри скрипта использовать эту функцию, что-бы ограничить просмотр страниц (кнопки не показывать, которые удаляют и прочее).Вообщем это стандартная практика.

Comment: Идея замечательная, но вариант с группами пользователей я отверг с самого начала, т.к. права доступа будут у каждого пользователя уникальны. Не делать же отдельную группу на каждого юзера?
В вопросе мне следовало пояснить, что это будет не обычный сайт, с пользователями, и регистрацией, а внутренний, корпоративный. Отсюда и вытекает такое необычное т.з.

Comment: Т.е у тебя каждому юзеру свой модуль?
Если так, то и храни у юзера id модуля. и потом если будут еще дополнительные таблицы, просто добавляй к юзеру еще поле и всё.

Comment: Нет, я сделал назначение прав именно таблицей-связкой (как написано в самом вопросе). Т.к. не каждый юзер получает отдельный модуль, а немного по другому. Расскажу на примере:
user 1 имеет доступ к модулю 1, 2, 3
user 2 имеет доступ к модулю 1, 4, 5
user 3 имеет доступ к модулю 6, 7, 8
При этом содержание самого модуля незначительно варьируется в зависимости от uid (id пользователя). Этот uid просто вставляется в конце запроса, в процессе формирования вывода: ....WHERE uid = $uid...вот так.

Comment: Задача осталась только в том, чтобы понять, каким образом должна выглядеть функция для запроса из нескольких таблиц.

Comment: SELECT `sometable1`.`somefields`, `sometable2`.`somefields` FROM `sometable1`,`sometable2`